# CA AutoSys scripting supports invoking anonymous & secured REST service?

Tags: autosys

Need to write a AutoSys script to invoke a REST service e.g. http://example.com/api/job/test-job and then setup a AutoSys Job.

AutoSys script supports REST service? If yes, will it support only anonymous REST service or it can support secured service as well?

Also, can it record HTTP response code? if yes, can it record HTTP response 200 OK as success and rest as failure when job runs?

Comment: Can you be more clear? Please mention what you're trying to achieve and what is preventing you from getting there.

Comment: I've now updated my question with details.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as an "Autosys script". Autosys is just a scheduling software, such as crontab is. You cannot create a script with it.

If you can create a script (using bash, ksh, python, perl,...) or a binary file that does the API call you need, then Autosys will be here to start it and give you back the log (if any) and the return code.

Answer (score 0):

See this link - https://support.ca.com/cadocs/0/CA%20Workload%20Automation%20System%20Agent%20r11%203-ENU/Bookshelf_Files/HTML/WebServicesCLIUser_11_3_1/index.htm

CA seems to support an Automation Agent using CLI through which you may invoke HTTP/HTTPS Web Services although there is no information provided on the response codes.

Also if FileWatcher can trigger HTTP requests, then some sort of REST interface to the pertinent web app functionality might work. There does not seem to be any way for AutoSys to directly invoke and record response for a REST service though.

As an alternative you can always interface with the web service using another platform (such as Java) and calling the same via AutoSys.